# comparison nouns with as as

Tags: comparisons

I have 2 questions about "as ... as comparison", I don't know if my sentences are correct or not.

1. There isn't as much **demand for buying a car** as **buying a
   house**
2. There aren't as many **reasons for fighting** as **peacing**

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a proofreading service, nor a writersr workshop; however, if you have a specific question about grammar or usage, we may be able to helo you. For example, *why* do you believe the sentences may not be correct, and what research have you attempted from reference works? I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for further guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the comparison correctly:  as much X as Y.

Since you're comparing two things, it's best to keep the syntax as parallel as possible so:

1. There isn't as much demand **for buying** a car as **for buying** a house.

X (car purchase) and Y (home purchase) are both expressed as prepositional phrases with "for."

The same with your second example.  Note that "peace" isn't an English verb.

2. There aren't as many reasons **for fighting** as **for making** peace.